# Show every key and values of an dynamically filled object in my screen - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to show every key and value of my incoming object, the object is filled dynamically, so if there is an object in the object I also need to show the key and value of that object too.

This is the object for example

```
info:{
address:{
   city: {__old: 'city1', __new: 'city2'}
   country: {__old: 'country1', __new: 'country2'}
   lineOne: {__old: 'lineOne1', __new: 'lineOne2'}
},
personalId: {__old: '55555555', __new: '555555556'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `JSON.stringify` like this:

```js
// import React from "react";

const address = {
  city: { __old: "city1", __new: "city2" },
  country: { __old: "country1", __new: "country2" },
  lineOne: { __old: "lineOne1", __new: "lineOne2" },
};

const App = () => {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(address, null, 3)}</pre>;
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Also you can use some library, like `JSONTree`:

```
import React from "react";
import JSONTree from "react-json-tree";

const address = {
  city: { __old: "city1", __new: "city2" },
  country: { __old: "country1", __new: "country2" },
  lineOne: { __old: "lineOne1", __new: "lineOne2" },
};

const App = () => {
  return <JSONTree data={address} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: To keep the line breaks and indentation I would recommend outputting into a `<pre>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: Cool, looks better with <pre>!